# MOS differential amplifier question please help

Tags: mosfet

A MOS differential amplifier with IT = 0.4 mA is shown in the figure. Assume γ1 = γ2 = 0 , λ1 = λ2 = 0, RD1 = RD2 = 2.5KΩ, VT0 = 0.7 V, μnCox = 100 μA/V^2 , 
(W/L)1 = 24 and (W/L)2 = 26.

(a)Estimate the value of the input differential signal Vid = VGS1 - VGS2 , that causes differential output voltage equal to zero.

(b)Estimate the value of the input differential signal Vid = VGS1 - VGS2 , that causes ID1 = 0.7IT.

(c)Estimate the common mode gain of the circuit, if the channel length modulation parameter of the transistor realizing IT is 0.05V^-1.

(d)Estimate the CMRR if RD1 = 2.5KΩ and RD2 = 2.6KΩ.
[image]

Comment: Homework questions with no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: @AnneFletchley We will help you where you are stuck. Show us your attempt and we'll drag you to the finish line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some hints.

I trust that M1 and M2 are actually both NMOS and that there's a mistake in the schematic drawing.

You should know (from lectures or nodal analysis) that: \$I_{ds1} + I_{ds2} = I_T\$

(a)

The differential output voltage equal to zero implies V0+ = V0-

Thus this must be true: \$I_{RD1} = I_{RD2}\$

And therefore also: \$I_{ds1} = I_{ds2} = 0.5 I_T = 0.2\$mA

So for M1 we have: \$24\frac{µ_nC_{ox}}{2}(V_{gs1}-0.7)^2 = 0.2\$mA

The equation for M2 is similar.

Solve for the two \$V_{gs}\$ and find their difference.

(b)

Remember: \$I_{ds1} + I_{ds2} = I_T\$

So if \$I_{ds1} = 0.7 I_T\$ then you must have \$I_{ds2} = 0.3 I_T\$.

The rest of the solution can be done as in (a), just change the currents.

(c)

Since the load is resistive the output common-mode will change linearly with \$I_T\$

Which node changes with Vcm_in and how does that affect Vcm_out ?

I think you can assume, for simplicity, that Ids1=Ids2 and both Vgs1 and Vgs2 are constant.

(d)

Here you should use small-signal analysis. First, you need to find estimates of the differential gain and then the common-mode gain.

It also seems reasonable to assume \$r_{ds1} \gg R_{D1}\$ and \$r_{ds2} \gg R_{D2}\$ then you can make simplifications like \$g_{m1}(r_{ds1} \parallel R_{D1}) \approx g_{m1}R_{D1}\$

Answer (score 0):

Anne The circuit has some intentional imbalances.

The (a) question uses W/L imbalances, 24 versus 26, thus 2/25 or 1/12.5 imbalance. Estimated.
If I recall correctly, the formula for long-channel FET transconductance is

K * W/L * Ve = K * W/L * (Vgs - Vt)

or

transconductance = 100 uA/V*V * 25 (we'll split the difference) * Ve

We need Ve at 0.4mA / 2 or at 0.2mA or at 200uA approx. in each side.

More accurately, we know the current in M2 will be 12.5% higher than in M1, assuming both gate are tied to GND (or both are tied to some voltage comfortably
above GND and comfortably below VDD).

Thus for (a) answer, we will need to raise Gate1 up by some millivolts (or 10s of milliVolts, or 100s of milliVolts), causing Idrain in M1 to increase by 6% and the Idrain of M2 to drop by that exact same 6% (the drain currents must sum to 400 uA, thus if Idrain M1 increases, Idrain M2 must decrease.)

But we still need Ve (the Vgs - Vt).

I believe the formula is Idrain = K/2 * W/L * Ve^2 for long-channel FETs, and we
want Idrain to be 200uA (or +-6% around 200uA, to be even more precise, and to
better impress your teachers.)
So

Idrain = 100uA/V^2 / 2 * 25 (or 24 or 26) * Ve^2

200uA = 50uA * 25 * Ve^2, and we need to solve for Ve.

200/50 = 25 * Ve^2, or 4 = 25 * Ve^2, or 4/25 = Ve^2, or Ve = 2/5

Thus Ve = 2/5 or 0.4 volts.

What is the transconductance? K * W/L * Ve = 100uA/V^2 * 25 (or 24 or 26) * 0.4

Transcondtance is also called "gm" (conductance mutual)

Thus gm = 100 * 25 * 0.4 * uA/V^2 * volt = 1,000 uA/volt (uA per volt, not volt^2)

Now assume Gate#2 is at VDD/2. How much must we raise Gate#1 above VDD/2?

We only need a 6% increase, from 200UA (approx.) to 212 uA. Our gm is 1,000uA/volt. We need 12 uA more.

Assuming everything is linearized (hence the question states "estimate"),
we need 0.012 volts extra on Gate1.

Answer to (a) is 12 milliVolts. Estimate.

You may choose to be more accurate, and that, also, is a good exercise.

Did this help? I fixed a couple typos; there may be more, or errors. Back later.

By the way, are you comfortable with LOADLINES?